# Wake on demand (WOD, WOL)

Tags: ssh, avahi, wakeonlan

I like to have my homeserver (running Ubuntu) automatically powered on when I am connecting via SSH from the internet.

I [successfully configured](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Wake_on_LAN) the server to listen for Wake On LAN (WOL) magic packets on the local network. I can poweroff the server and then send a WOL magic package with [wol](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wake-on-lan/) to start the server. Everything is working :)

But i like to go further: My router (Apple Airport Extreme) is capable of Wake On Demand (WOD). But how can I register my server (e.g. with Avahi) to the router, so that it knows to wake the server when connecting via SSH?

Edit: Some details: If the server is already running, i can connect from the internet via SSH; port forwarding is correctly set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something to emulate a [Bonjour Sleep Proxy](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3774) client and there is something that does do that: [Sleep Proxy Client](https://github.com/awein/SleepProxyClient).

I'd really recommend reading through that page but the instructions for installing it are pretty simple:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://repo.weinlein.info unstable main'
echo '-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.10 (GNU/Linux)
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=kSu4
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----' | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sleepproxyclient
```